# Series expansion of ArcTan function

Tags: taylor-expansion, mathematica

I have to expand a series for Arctan near `0` using Mathematica or mupad in Matlab. However, it does not work. Please have a look at below expansions for `t` being small:

```
xx[t_] := t^2*x[2] + t^3*x[3] + t^4*x[4] + t^5*x[5] + t^6*x[6] + O[t]^7;
yy[t_] := y[0] + t* y[1] + t^2*y[2] + t^3*y[3] + t^4 * y[4] + t^5*y[5] + 
          t^6*y[6] + O[t]^7;
arc[t_] = ArcTan[(1 - yy[t])*Sqrt[k/xx[t]]]
arc2[t_] = Series[ArcTan[(1 - yy[t])*Sqrt[k/xx[t]]], {t, 0, 3}]
```

Mathematica does give me an answer for `arc[]` and `arc2[]`. But it is not what I wanted. It gives me `Floor`and`Arg` in the answer.

I want just a series expansion of ArcTan around t=0 until order t^3 for small t.

When I type  `(1 - yy[t])*Sqrt[k/xx[t]]     (*)` , it gives me the series being `order of` `t^(-1)`. We all know that

```
ArcTan [x] ~ x - x^3/3 + x^5/5 -x^7/7 +  ...      (**)
```

Now, because of this fact in (**) and the first term : t^(-1) term in `(*)` , `arc2[t]` expansion above should go until `t^(-infinity)` where `t` is small.

Could you please give me a hint for this : how to find `arc2[]`  ? `xx[t] and yy[t] are real valued.` Maybe it recognises these as `complex valued functions` and that is why it gives `floor` and `Arg` in the answer.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want a Taylor series of the function $x^{-1/2}\tan^{1}x$ (?) The problem with that is the the first derivative diverges at $x=0$

Comment: @caverac , thanks so much . What I would like to know is `ArcTan series expansion of (A/t + B + C*t + O(t^2)) for small t`      where `A, B, C` are constants. The first term causes issue as it is `large`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x)=\tan^{-1}(a/x+b+cx + O(x^2))$ these are a few terms of the expansion

1. $O(x^0)$:

   $$
    f^{(0)}(0) = \lim_{x\to 0+}f(x) = \pi/2
    $$
2. $O(x^1)$:

   $$
    f^{(1)}(0) = \lim_{x\to 0+}f'(x) = -\frac{1}{a}
    $$
3. $O(x^2)$:

   $$
    f^{(2)}(0) = \lim_{x\to 0+}f''(x) = \frac{2b}{a^2}
    $$

The Taylor expansion of $f(x)$ is then

$$
f(x) = \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{x}{a} + \frac{bx^2}{a^2} + O(x^3)
$$

Comment: Thanks @caverac , should not the third term be `bx^2/a^2` in your f(x) answer due to the factorial of 2!.

Comment: @Meva You're right, just fixed it